# how can I convert number to date?

Tags: r

I have a problem with the as.date function.
I have a list of normal date shows in the excel, but when I import it in R, it becomes numbers, like 33584. I understand that it counts since a specific day. I want to set up my date in the form of "dd-mm-yy".

The original data is:
[how the "date" variable looks like in r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4ckv.png)

I've tried:

```
as.date <- function(x, origin = getOption(date.origin)){
  origin <- ifelse(is.null(origin), "1900-01-01", origin)
  as.Date(date, origin)
}
```

and also simply
`as.Date(43324, origin = "1900-01-01")`
but none of them works. it shows the error: do not know how to convert '.' to class “Date”

Thank you guys!

Comment: (1) `ifelse` is wrong here, use `if (is.null(origin)) origin <- "1900-01-01"`. (2) I don't get that error with that code.

Comment: BTW, another way to deal with empty origin is `function(x, origin = getOption(date.origin, "1900-01-01"))`

Comment: @r2evans, thank you, that helps! But I'm also having troubles on converting a list of date numbers to the normal date format. Like I have a "mydate" variable with 100 dates, and I want to convert all of them, but I don't know where and when should I introduce the date origin.

Comment: I can't help any more without sample data. Please provide sample data using `dput(..)` or `data.frame(..)`; good references for making the question complete and reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 1):

The janitor package has a pair of functions designed to deal with reading Excel dates in R. See the following links for usage examples:

- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/janitor/versions/2.0.1/topics/excel_numeric_to_date
- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/janitor/versions/2.0.1/topics/convert_to_date

```
janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(43324)
[1] "2018-08-12"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across excel sheets read in with `readxl::read_xls()` that read date columns in as strings like "43488" (especially when there is a cell somewhere else that has a non-date value). I use

```
xldate<- function(x) {
  xn <- as.numeric(x)
  x <- as.Date(xn, origin="1899-12-30")
}

d <- data.frame(date=c("43488"))
d$actual_date <- xldate(d$date)
print(d$actual_date)
# [1] "2019-01-23"
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates are notoriously annoying. I would highly recommend the `lubridate` package for dealing with them. https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/

Use `as_date()` from `lubridate` to read numeric dates if you need to.

You can use `format()` to put it in dd-mm-yy.

```
library(lubridate)

date_vector <- as_date(c(33584, 33585), origin = lubridate::origin)

formatted_date_vector <- format(date_vector, "%d-%m-%y")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `convertToDateTime` function from `openxlsx` package which is also a great package for importing and exporting the dataframes.

```
convertToDateTime(43324, origin = "1900-01-01")
```

If your date does not make sense, try changing the `origin`. There are couple different dates, such as `"1970-01-01", "1899-12-30"`, etc.